# Upgrading old app from 2017 to heroku-20 stack, cannot get test app to work

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

Following the instructions on this page: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrading-to-the-latest-stack#testing-an-app-on-a-new-stack to upgrade my old 2017 app to heroku-20 stack. I decided to set up and test a test app before upgrading the actual program. I am able to get up to the step that says:

Push the source to the test app’s remote:

```
git push heroku-20 master
Counting objects: 67, done.
...
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rack
...
```

But upon attempting to compile I get an error saying that precompiling assets failed.

Per suggestions from others, I tried creating a new branch main, moving my code and git history from master to main, then deleting master to push directly from main. This resulted in similar error message. In the end I was only able to make progress after I ran bundle install and pushed my gemfile.lock changes to origin main remote. Terminal said app deployed successfully, but when you actually load the app at https://splurty-heroku-20.herokuapp.com/ , you get an error message telling you to check heroku logs, which say the following:

```
[Web Dev]:  /vagrant/src/splurty $ heroku logs --remote heroku-20
2022-05-24T19:53:04.642229+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.0.7.2 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:45546
2022-05-24T19:53:04.642232+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2022-05-24T19:53:04.642232+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2022-05-24T19:53:04.759912+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-05-24T19:53:04.828239+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-05-24T19:53:04.830939+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-05-24T19:53:08.148972+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p ${PORT:-5000} -e production`
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540031+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/type/adapter_specific_registry.rb:7:in `add_modifier': wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2) (ArgumentError)
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540040+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/type.rb:22:in `add_modifier'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540057+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:827:in `<class:PostgreSQLAdapter>'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540060+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:69:in `<module:ConnectionAdapters>'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540060+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540061+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540061+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540061+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540062+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540062+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540064+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:174:in `spec'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540066+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `establish_connection'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540068+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:125:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540079+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:69:in `instance_eval'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540081+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:69:in `block in execute_hook'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540082+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:60:in `with_execution_control'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540090+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:65:in `execute_hook'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540092+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:50:in `block in run_load_hooks'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540094+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `each'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540101+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `run_load_hooks'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540103+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/base.rb:324:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540105+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/base.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540113+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540115+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540116+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540131+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540133+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/app/models/application_record.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540141+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540142+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540144+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540152+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540154+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:380:in `block in require_or_load'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540156+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `block in load_interlock'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540163+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:12:in `block in loading'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540165+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:150:in `exclusive'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540167+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:11:in `loading'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540175+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `load_interlock'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540176+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:358:in `require_or_load'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540178+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:336:in `depend_on'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540186+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:252:in `require_dependency'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540188+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:476:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540195+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `each'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540197+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `block in eager_load!'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540204+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:473:in `each'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540206+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:473:in `eager_load!'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540214+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:354:in `eager_load!'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540215+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:59:in `each'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540217+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:59:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540225+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540227+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540228+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540236+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540238+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540240+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540248+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540249+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540251+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540259+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540261+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540262+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540270+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540272+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540274+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540282+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540283+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540285+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540293+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540295+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540297+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540305+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540306+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540314+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:84:in `app'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540315+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540322+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:312:in `block in start'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540324+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:379:in `handle_profiling'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540331+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:311:in `start'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540333+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:104:in `start'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540335+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:90:in `block in server'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540343+00:00 app[web.1]: from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540345+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540346+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540354+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540356+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:9:in `require'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.540358+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
2022-05-24T19:53:11.543722+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2022-05-24T19:53:11.543723+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.0.7.2 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:9192
2022-05-24T19:53:11.543723+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2022-05-24T19:53:11.543724+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2022-05-24T19:53:11.672857+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-05-24T19:53:11.726990+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-05-24T19:54:00.704906+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=splurty-heroku-20.herokuapp.com request_id=3ec976c6-5e14-4983-915e-7d69832d14c9 fwd="73.104.56.230" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-05-24T19:54:00.955731+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=splurty-heroku-20.herokuapp.com request_id=660c66b0-35e0-45cc-92ab-424b11fc7c43 fwd="73.104.56.230" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-05-24T19:54:04.266633+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=splurty-heroku-20.herokuapp.com request_id=594da8ec-15df-4289-8829-60d2206ecedf fwd="73.104.56.230" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
[Web Dev]:  /vagrant/src/splurty $
```